# Display mongodb data read by php using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a some a php file that reads data from a local mongodb database and am trying to use angularjs to read this data and display it on a html table. Currently I am able to display and see the data in the console using XMLHttpRequest. But nothing is displayed on the page (not even the {{}}). It just a blank page. How can I get display this data using angularjs?

This is what one of the data items displayed in the console:

```
{_id: {…}, name: "Fri Oct 04 2019 06:10:36 GMT+0000 (UTC)", action: "Test action", ao: "MC"}
```

HTML with JS and AngularJS code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Read All MongoDB</title>
  <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController" class="content">
     <table id="searchTextResults">
       <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
         <td>{{item.date}}</td>
         <td>{{item.action}}</td>
         <td>{{item.ao}}</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
  </div>
<script>
    // using XMLHttpRequest to display data in the console
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.onload = function() {
            var data = this.responseText;
            var parsed = JSON.parse(`[${data}]`);
            console.log(parsed);
            for(let i = 0; i < parsed.length; i++) {
                    console.log(parsed[i]);
            }
    };
    oReq.open("get", "get-data.php", true);
    oReq.send();

    // trying to use angularjs to display data in the html table
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {
            $http.get('get-data.php').then(function(response) {
                    $scope.items = response.items;
            });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php

try {

    $mng = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    $query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query([]);

    $rows = $mng->executeQuery("comments.comments", $query);

    $items = array();
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        array_push($items, $row);
        #echo "$row->name : $row->price\n";
    }

     echo json_encode($items);

} catch (MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception $e) {

    $filename = basename(__FILE__);

    echo "The $filename script has experienced an error.\n";
    echo "It failed with the following exception:\n";

    echo "Exception:", $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    echo "In file:", $e->getFile(), "\n";
    echo "On line:", $e->getLine(), "\n";
}

?>
```